# Problems installing ping in docker

Tags: linux, ubuntu, installation, docker

I am trying to follow the docker tutorial but in a virtual machine. I've tried to install ping in ubuntu docker container with the command

```
sudo docker run ubuntu apt-get install ping
```

The problem is that docker doesn't install anything and gives the answer as follows

```
$ sudo docker run ubuntu apt-get install ping
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Package ping is a virtual package provided by:
  inetutils-ping 2:1.8-6
  iputils-ping 3:20101006-1ubuntu1

E: Package 'ping' has no installation candidate
$
```

The same problem appears when I'm trying to install anything.

These are my images:

```
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             VIRTUAL SIZE
<none>              <none>              3a28cc5bcc53        19 minutes ago      247.6 MB
baselDaemon         latest              4e892058b0b2        4 days ago          204.4 MB
ubuntu              13.10               9f676bd305a4        2 weeks ago         178 MB
ubuntu              saucy               9f676bd305a4        2 weeks ago         178 MB
ubuntu              13.04               eb601b8965b8        2 weeks ago         166.5 MB
ubuntu              raring              eb601b8965b8        2 weeks ago         166.5 MB
ubuntu              12.10               5ac751e8d623        2 weeks ago         161 MB
ubuntu              quantal             5ac751e8d623        2 weeks ago         161 MB
ubuntu              10.04               9cc9ea5ea540        2 weeks ago         180.8 MB
ubuntu              lucid               9cc9ea5ea540        2 weeks ago         180.8 MB
ubuntu              12.04               9cd978db300e        2 weeks ago         204.4 MB
ubuntu              latest              9cd978db300e        2 weeks ago         204.4 MB
ubuntu              precise             9cd978db300e        2 weeks ago         204.4 MB
learn/tutorial      latest              8dbd9e392a96        10 months ago       128 MB
```

Also, when I run `sudo docker run ubuntu apt-get install ping` what is the 'ubuntu' used here?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Visit : http://askubuntu.com/q/14685

Comment: If your installing ping, may be useful to also include nslookup; apt-get install dnsutils

Answer (score 97):

According to:

```
Package ping is a virtual package provided by:
  inetutils-ping 2:1.8-6
  iputils-ping 3:20101006-1ubuntu1

E: Package 'ping' has no installation candidate
```

Try with:

```
sudo docker run ubuntu apt-get install iputils-ping
```

You choose a 'ubuntu' with repository:tag in place of IMAGE in RUN command

```
sudo docker run ubuntu:lucid command
```

Comment: Which command did you run to get this info "Package ping is a virtual package provided by: ..."?

Comment: bash shows that message when you call a command that is not found. Not sure how though.

Answer (score 29):

run `apt-get update` once before the install:

```
sudo docker run ubuntu apt-get update
```

see [What does `sudo apt-get update` do?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/222348/what-does-sudo-apt-get-update-do)

> `apt-get update` downloads the package lists from the repositories and
>   "updates" them to get information on the newest versions of packages
>   and their dependencies.

Comment: This works prefectly.

docker run -it ubuntu bash, then:
apt-get update; 
apt-get install iputils-ping

Answer (score 17):

Yeah ultimately you need to know about three different topics:

1. Docker
2. Ubuntu
3. APT repositories

Here's how I like to get Ubuntu running in a Docker container:

```
docker run -i -t ubuntu:16.04 /bin/bash
```

Echoing what @Michael_Scharf recommends, here's how you update your APT repositories:

```
apt-get update
```

Then working back to @VTacius' solution, here's how to install the IP utilities responsible for the ping command:

```
apt-get install iputils-ping
```

Then to verify things are working as expected:

```
which ping
ping superuser.com
```

Comment: Your answer is like the others

Comment: Perhaps that's true.  I just found that each answer in and of itself didn't resolve my problem.  Each answer was specific to a different piece of the puzzle, and when applied in the correct order, the combination of these other answers did resolve my issue.

Comment: It is the correct answer due the complete set of instructions.

Answer (score 2):

Faced the same issue when using ubuntu 16.04 image in docker.

The following steps helped me resolve this issue.

1. Login to docker container as bash

   ```
   $ docker exec -it <conatiner id> bash
   ```
2. inside the docker container, execute following commands. First update apt-get

   ```
   $ apt-get update
   ```
3. Second install iputils-ping

   ```
   $ apt-get install iputils-ping
   ```

This should work.